# How to resolve corrupted index for region in GEMFIRE

Tags: gemfire, geode, gfsh

Unable to query region (select * from /xxx), getting the following error message:
**Query could not be executed due to - orgapachegeodeSerializationException - Could not create an Instance of com.xxx
**
However if I query via GFSH, I am able to query the first few lines.
After digging further, found the following in the logs:
**Updating the Index xxx.yyy failed. The index is corrupted and marked as invalid.**

Tried removing via GFSH (remove --region=/xxx --all=true) but failed and got the following error message:
**Region xxx Not Found**.

How can I resolve the corrupted index issue?

Comment: Have you tried just destroying and recreating the index?